# Tomcat 404 http resource not found error

Tags: tomcat7

I am getting this error when I started tomcat in my eclipse. My tomact version is 7.0.55. After this I am getting error popup containing "Server Tomcat v7.0 at localhost failed to start." message. please help me.

[image: http://i.s]tack.imgur.com/Vg74N.png